# Mac Catalyst Font issue on export

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont, mac-catalyst

I'm currently porting an iPad app to macOS, and while it's working fine on my computer, it will instantly crash on anybody's else, with the following error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/me/myProject/MyFile.swift, line 20

Strangely, my user is referenced in the path, but the file seems to open fine.

The line that causes the issue is:

```
UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: size)
```

The app works fine on iPad, so maybe there's an action related to font files that I'm unaware of?

This happens when using either the development binary or the archived / exported development binary.

The issue disappears when installing the custom fonts on the destination computer. Surely, the end user shouldn't have to do that.

The issue doesn't happen on the App Store version of the app.